# Customize Org agenda entry based on properties in TODO items

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to show certain icons to the left of TODO items in the agenda based on the presence of a property.

For example, if TODO item A has the "important" property, show an exclamation mark:

```
!  TODO A
   TODO B
```

It looks like this can be customized with `org-agenda-prefix-format` using the `%(expression)` syntax, but I encounter bizarre issues when using the following syntax:

```
(defun show-exclamation-if-important()
  (save-window-excursion
    (org-agenda-goto)
    (if (org-entry-properties (point) "important")
        "!"
      " ")))
```

This combined with using `%(show-exclamation-if-important)` returns `user-error: Command not allowed in this line`. It seems to be an issue with the excursion of some sorts?

Simply put, how can I get a return value of the properties of a TODO item while on the corresponding agenda entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is thrown by `org-agenda-goto` when it can't find an agenda entry corresponding to point.  After some further investigation, it looks like this is because the function is actually *not called from the agenda*, but rather from the file containing the entry.  That is, you're already where `org-agenda-goto` would put you, so you don't need either that or the `save-window-excursion`:

```el
(defun show-exclamation-if-important () 
  (if (org-entry-properties (point) "important") "!" " "))
```